# Calculate the results of one query as a percentage of another in SQL

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook, percentage, impala

I am trying to calculate the number of people with impaired eyesight against the number of people who have had an eye test. I have managed to calculate the totals for both the number of people with impaired eyesight (TotalDiagnosed) and the total number of evaluations (TotalEvaluated):

```
! impala-shell -q 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT eyesight_evaluation.patient_id FROM eyesight_evaluation WHERE severity_of_sight_loss IN ("Slight","Mild","Moderate","Moderately Severe","Severe","Profound")) AS TotalDiagnosed;'

! impala-shell -q 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT eyesight_evaluation.patient_id) AS TotalEvaluated FROM eyesight_evaluation;'
```

What I am unsure of is how to work out the percentage. I attempted

```
! impala-shell -q 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT eyesight_evaluation.patient_id) AS TotalEvaluated FROM eyesight_evaluation;'
```

but it returned

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
>   ...osed, TotalEvaluated ROUND(TotalDiagnosed * 100.0 /Tot...
>                                ^
>   Encountered: (
>   Expected: CROSS, FROM, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, JOIN, LEFT, LIMIT, OFFSET, ON, ORDER, RIGHT, >STRAIGHT_JOIN, TABLESAMPLE, UNION, USING, WHERE, COMMA
>
> CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Can anybody help me work out the percentage? I am using Impala and a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN severity_of_sight_loss IN ('Slight', 'Mild', 'Moderate', 'Moderately Severe', 'Severe', 'Profound') THEN ee.patient_id END) * 1.0 /
        COUNT(DISTINCT eyesight_evaluation.patient_id)
       )
FROM eyesight_evaluation ee;
```